# SwiftUI pick a value from a list with ontap gesture

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, ontouch

i'm try to pick some value from a swiftUI list with the ontapGesture.

I have a Searchlist of item, the user need to choose one item and then the app will send the choice to an array that later will be use for other info.

now my problem is how do I do that? how can do it? 
as you can see from the code below, I want to pick the value of the item.icaoAirport corresponding to that raw and pass to an array.

```
 List(dm.vettoreAeroporti.filter{
                //                    $0.icaoCode.contains(searchTerm)
                $0.icaoAirport.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
            }) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.icaoAirport).bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Text(item.nameAirport)

                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                    self.dm.openFileJson(fileName: "data")
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                // ?? I need to take the value of the item.icaoAirport corresponding to that raw

            }
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 31):

While your, Damiano, answer is right it works only on tap on the `Text`.
Sometimes it is needed to have the whole row tappable, so here is the solution for this case:

```
List(items) { item in
    HStack {
        Text(item.icaoAirport).bold()
        Spacer()
        Text(item.nameAirport)
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture {
        print("touched item \(item)")
    }
}
```

Thanks Paul for this (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape)

Note, that if you have content only on one side of the `HStack` e.g:

```
HStack {
    Text("Some text") // This text will be on the left side
}
```

then the `.contentShape(Rectange())` will work only for the width of the text. So to enable it for the whole width just add a trailing `Spacer()` like this:

```
HStack {
    Text("Some text")
    Spacer() // This will take all the space from the end of the text up to the end of the whole row
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

Comment: Awesome, it works for me on space with text and without text ;)

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue:

```
HStack {
    Text(item.icaoAirport).bold()
    Spacer()
    Text(item.nameAirport)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("touched item \(item.icaoAirport)")        
        }
}
```

Comment: this solution is not good. The text will be tappable but not the cell where the text is, what is not good.

Answer (score 2):

```
List {
        ForEach(Type.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                FilterRow(Color: type.Color,
                          title: type.Title)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("Ammu type:\(type)")

                            }
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate answer, please remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This one is quite old but the accepted answers are pretty strange. I was able to achieve this effect in a much simpler way. Consider:

```swift
List {
  ForEach(myItems) { item in
    Button {
      // action
    } label: {
      Text(item.name)
    }
  }
}
```

Now doing it this way, the button is edge-to-edge in the row. However, the button is now the accent color of your app. That's probably not what you want! So I tried adding:

```swift
Button(...)
  .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

The text of the button is now the primary foreground color, great! But there's a different problem now! The button no longer goes edge-to-edge, it's only the text. To fix this, i instead:

```swift
Button(...)
  .foregroundColor(.primary)
```

This is edge-to-edge with primary color text and custom actions. No need to create HStacks with spacers and an onTap, it's all just handled. OP's post has text on both sides so likely still needs an HStack for their specific usecase but a `Button` is still probably a better choice.