# SwiftUI: Make remaining area of list item detect clicks

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui, selection

I have a navigation sidebar on my macOS app built on a custom navigation system.
To navigate to different views I detect `.onTapGesture`s of the list items like so:

```
List (selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(items, id:\.id) { item in
        getNavButton(navItem: item) //an HStack with an Image and a Text view
            .onTapGesture {
                //change selection
                //navigate to desired view...
            }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click on an item, it highlights the selection on the sidebar as intented. The problem is that it does not trigger the `.onTapGesture` unless the click is made on the `NavButton`.

To fix this I tried increasing the bounds of the `HStack` that contains the button components. I also tried adding a `Spacer` inside the stack.

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "house")
    Text("some text...")
    Spacer()
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

This still leaves a small area around the button that does not detect my clicks, seen below. Note: when clicks happen in the red area, they are detected. The red color is pure styling.

[image: Problem image 1]

---

How can I fill the remaining area around the button?
Also, if this approach is ineffective, how should I detect changes in selection?

Comment: @loremipsum No, the red color is there to indicate the missing area around the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64942577/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi No, my problem is not with the color. The color is a pure indication of the missing area. I'm having difficulty making the entire area detect my clicks.

Comment: Do you have `.padding()` anywhere that view is being touched?

Comment: @xTwisteDx This is all of the styling I am using. There is no other styling on any of the objects. I will be trying a combined `.padding` and `.offset` solution now that you mentioned it. Thank you.

Comment: Add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to your button, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58500295/swiftui-pick-a-value-from-a-list-with-ontap-gesture