# SwiftUI: Detect click on already selected list item

Tags: swift, list, listview, swiftui, selection

I have a `List` view with several items. All of then serve navigation purposes and all are `Text`. I **cannot** use `NavigationLink`s for this app.

That said, I am monitoring the list selection through a `@State` variable.

```
@State private var selection: String?
```

I print its value whever the view gets updated. It normally prints the unique `id` of every item when selecting **different** items of the list.

The problem is when trying to select the **same item again**: in this case the view does not get updated, and I don't see the debug message in my console.

I would like to be able to press on a list item to display a view, and then be able to press on it again, despite it already being selected because I have logic I would like to run (for example: manual view refresh).

How can I detect the re-selection of an already selected list item?

For any questions, please let me know. Thank you for your help!

---

#### Update 1

This is the code I am using:
**Helper list item struct:**

```
struct NavItem {
    let id: String
    let text: String
}
```

**List:**

```
struct NavList: View {
    
    @Binding private var selection: String?
    private var listItems: [NavItem]
    
    //note:
    //selection is a @State variable declared in a parent struct and passed here.
    //This is optional. I could declare it as a @state too.
    init(listItems: [NavItem], selection: Binding<String?>) { 
        self.listItems = listItems
        self._selection = selection
        debugPrint(self.selection)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List (selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(listItems, id:\.id) { item in 
                Text(item.text)
                    .tag(item.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Note 1**: I already know this problem can be approached by using the `.onTapGesture` modifier. This solution seems to not be optimal. I tried seeking help for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450904/swiftui-make-remaining-area-of-list-item-detect-clicks).

**Note 2**: In the project, the `struct` that contains the list conforms to `View`. When that view is displayed, it has the `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())` modifier added. This might be relevant.

Comment: can you please show more code ?

Comment: @Osman I added code to my question. With this you should be able to reproduce the question after adding some example data as list items...

Comment: How is `.onTapGesture` not optimal?

Comment: @Yrb As I asked earlier today in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450904/swiftui-make-remaining-area-of-list-item-detect-clicks (which was __wrongfully__ closed as "already having an answer"), the `.onTapGesture` does not cover the entirety of the list. The highlight extends __around__ the selected item.  
This leaves room for the user to select the item, but not get a response from their action. I was unable to sovle this issue or get any help, thus, I dubbed it not optimal.

Comment: I saw that one. I am not sure you understood the link and the comments. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a number of ways to do what you want,
try this with `.onTapGesture{..}`

```
    List (selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(listItems, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.text)
                .tag(item.id)
                .padding(10)
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                .frame(minWidth: 111, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("----> " + item.text)
                }
        }
    }
```

or you can use a `Button` instead of `onTapGesture`;

```
    List (selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(listItems, id: \.id) { item in
            Button(action: { print("----> " + item.text) }) {
                Text(item.text)
            }
                .padding(10)
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .tag(item.id)
            .frame(minWidth: 111, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
```

EDIT: full test code:

This is the code I used in my tests:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
    }
}

struct NavItem {
    let id: String
    let text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var listItems: [NavItem] = [NavItem(id: "1", text: "1"),
                                              NavItem(id: "2", text: "2"),
                                              NavItem(id: "3", text: "3"),
                                              NavItem(id: "4", text: "4")]
    @State private var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List (selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(listItems, id:\.id) { item in
                Button(action: { print("----> " + item.text) }) {
                    Text(item.text)
                }
                .padding(10)
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,leading: -5, bottom: 0, trailing: -5))
                .frame(minWidth: 111, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .tag(item.id)
                .background(Color.red)  // <--- last modifier
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: He beat me to it. The trick to what you want is setting the frame of the clicked item. This expands the touch size.

Comment: The first solution, as mentioed in the comments, is not optimal. This has already been attempted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450904/swiftui-make-remaining-area-of-list-item-detect-clicks?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well.
The button has the same issue: when the item is selected, there is a small area left around the button that does not perform any action when clicked.
Regardless, thank you very much for your contribution!
-----
Tested the first solution: it produces the exact same result as the image in linked question.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution to the small area left around the button.

Comment: Adding `.listRowInsets` modifier is indeed improving things! The top and bottom area is now covered by the item. There is a still a very slight area left on the two sides. Very clever!

Comment: works very well as is in my tests. You could try with a small negative value for the leading/trailing parameters.

Comment: @workingdog I am currently tinkering with negative values for `.trailing` and `.leading` . It does not seem to work as well. `.offset` seems ineffective as well.

Comment: Are you really using the code that you are showing us? Because that works very well  in my tests, including a -5 for leading and trailing values.

Comment: @workingdog Yes, I am working with the code I have provided in this question to make sure there is absolutely nothing else interfering. On that note, the current state is this (if you add `.background(Color.red)` modifier): https://imgur.com/a/5IYM3ca - As you can see a small area on the sides remains. (Note: there is NO bottom overflow, this is from the item below!)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full code I'm using. Your picture shows a icon and Home text, this is not from the code you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237860/discussion-between-lae-and-workingdog).

Comment: thanks, but I don't do chats.